# CocoaPods importing a framework to source code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

In my pod for iOS, I have a essentially items:

1. Open-source classes (.m & .h files)
2. MyFramework.framework (.framework directory, header files, and .bundle for resources)

One of the open-source classes calls `import <MyFramework.MyFramework.h>` so it can use the components of MyFramework in its implementation. But because of this, I'm having trouble getting the podspec to pass the spec lint test (`pod spec lint MyCocoapod.podspec`). When I run the spec lint validation, it says:

```
ERROR | [iOS] [xcodebuild]  .../MyFile.h:54:9: fatal error: 'MyFramework/MyFramework.h' file not found
```

While investigating, I noticed that the podspec does pass the spec lint validation if I remove that open-source class in the podspec's source_files section, `s.source_files = 'MyFiles.{h,m}'`. Any idea why my class can't import my custom framework during the spec lint validation?

The relevant code in the podspec looks like this:

```
s.preserve_paths      = 'myframework/MyFramework.framework'
s.frameworks          = 'Foundation', 'MyFramework'
s.xcconfig            = { 'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(SRCROOT)/myframework/' }
s.public_header_files = 'MyFramework.framework/Headers/*.h', 'SourceCode/*.h'
s.source_files        = 'SourceCode/*.{h,m}'  # Crashes here - Source_file imports MyFramework.h. If I take this out, it passes spec lint validation
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**EDIT** This process is now entirely handled by the [`vendored_frameworks`](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#vendored_frameworks) option. This handles preserving the paths, the framework search paths, and linking to the project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So if my cocoapod were **just** a framework, this works. But the pod also has some source_code (.m & .h files) to be distributed as well. Within the source_code (.m) of my pod, an `#import <MyFramework.framework>` happens, and that's where the lint spec fails validation.

Comment: Adding `source_files` to the podspec as well shouldn't have any affect on importing your framework. What's the error that CocoaPods is showing in the lint? (Also make sure you're using the newest version `gem update`)

Comment: Hmm, the error is above in the question field... `ERROR |...`. (I just added relevant code from my podspec) Perhaps I'm not importing the framework correctly in the first place, which is why the source_files can't import the framework properly either. I will investigate this and get back to you.

Comment: Also look at `exlucde_files` [here](http://docs.cocoapods.org/specification.html#exclude_files) if you think it's being imported twice.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the `Foo` in my `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`, as per your update. Thanks for tip.

Comment: Is there any actual documentation for vendored_frameworks? This is not documentation: https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#vendored_frameworks. For example, I don't know if vendored_frameworks will automatically compile my pod into a framework and put it there? (Doesn't happen, so far...) Or, am I supposed to create the framework and then put it there? Cocoapods documentation is frustratingly terse...

Comment: `vendored_frameworks` is only for shipping pre-compiled frameworks. If you're shipping your source files with this pod you shouldn't need this attribute.

Comment: I'm specifically trying to figure out how to ship a library without source code, while still maintaining the convenience of developing that library using Cocoapods. The podspec described [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3538) is the only thing I can find that seems helpful. But I'm thinking I'll need to use Cocoapods-Rome or cocoapods-packager to make the framework in the first place, as it starts life as a podspec.

Comment: You should create a framework target in your project. Then you can archive and distribute that.

Comment: I am using `vendored_frameworks` but have the exact same issue as the OP. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

To include a framework you can use:

`s.vendored_frameworks = 'path/to/SomeFramework.framework'`

To include bundle files do:

`s.resources ='path/to/SomeBundle.bundle'`